# problem with h:inputtext in Rich:ModalPanel

Tags: richfaces

I am using rich:modalpanel for editing some values so when user clicks on edit the popup will appear with some prefilled values.

For popup i am using ModalPanel, the problem is for the first time it is populating the right values but from second time onwards the input text values are not getting updated. I tried displaying same values using outputtext and then i am getting the correct values.

Any suggestion is welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

This could be one reason.
Your modal panel must be showing the values set in the bean property. 
After you update the value in the modal panel , are you submitting the form or updating the bean property in ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

Try reRender="parentId" on the command component (commandButton or commandLink) within the modalPanel that you click on to hide it. reRender will make sure that the current values on the parent are displayed. Of course, you will have to use some kind of action or actionListener on that command component to update the values on the bean that the parent is displaying.